# Trying to login on webpage using PowerShell but receiving invalid username and password

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, com, html

I am trying to login on page using PS but receiving invalid username and password error, even though they are correct.

Code:

```
$username ='xxxx'
$password ='xxx'
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("https://xxxxxx") 
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100} 
$ie.document.getElementById("username").value= "$username" 
$ie.document.getElementById("password").value = "$password" 
$loginBtn = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('input') | Where-Object 
{$_.Type -eq 'submit' -and $_.Value -eq 'Sign In'}
$loginBtn.click()
```

HTML's

Username:

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="  " value="" autocomplete="off" id="username" placeholder="Username">
```

Password:

```
<input type="password" name="password" class="  " value="" autocomplete="off" id="password" placeholder="Password">
```

Sign In :

```
<input class="splButton-primary btn" type="submit" value="Sign in">
```

Comment: Did you try doing the same in IE , with out using the code with same credentials ?

Comment: I am able to login with credentials in IE not by running the script